# Why does Open Graph use <meta property=.... in their example code?

Tags: facebook, xhtml

As far as I can tell, `property` is not a valid attribute of the `<meta>` tag in any of HTML 3, 4, XHTML-Transitional or XHTML-Strict. So why does the Open Graph Protocol (and Facebook's API docs) specify example code like this?

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
```

This doesn't validate. Changing `property` to `name` does validate, and I can verify that, at least on Facebook, it still works as intended. So why do they use `property` in their example code?

http://opengraphprotocol.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They define their own [custom DTD](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customdtds2/) ([definition of DTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition)). This allows them to create their own extension to the HTML standard and as long as they follow their own DTD they are technically ok. It won't be valid HTML but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Why not?  How hard would it have been to do it right?

Comment: Does it have to be pure HTML to be right?

Comment: Just because they can, doesn't mean they should. The answer doesn't clarify why they did that in the first place. Why didn't they use `name` instead of `property`? Was it necessary?

Comment: Necro bump! Here's the spec for OG: https://ogp.me/ _"The RDF schema (in Turtle) can be found at https://ogp.me/ns."_ HTLM5 validation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25575860/2586761